# How to show d3.js usa map with some state name outside the state pointing to it

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

im using d3.js  and d3-geo to  get  USA map i need to  have some state names inside the state itself while others states should have names outside the map with a line pointing to the corresponding state.
for example  large states like Texas should contain the names inside them while smaller states like Maryland  will be outside .

im new to d3.js any help is welcome im new to d3.js and i cannot find any useful resource for this

thanks in advance

i need  my  map  to look something like of this sort
[image]

Answer (score 1):

use d3-tip for data visualization its a dynamic tooltip